# BeutifulSoap4 and escaped data in html

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Html I load into BeutifulSoap4 is in this format:

```
\\u003C/span\\u003E\\u003Ca href=\\"javascript:void(0)\\" class=\\"something something22\\"\\u003EShowMore\\u003C/a\\u003E\\u003C/span\\u003E\\u003Cspan style=\\"display:none\\" class=\\"review-full-text\\"\\u003ESomething else....
```

And because of this BeutifulSoap4 can't find html tags, for example, it normally is able to:

```
bsoup1.find_all("div", class_="some_class")
```

Is there a standard way to fix that?

Comment: how do you get this string ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `unicode_escape` encoding

```
data = '\\u003C/span\\u003E\\u003Ca href=\\"javascript:void(0)\\" class=\\"something something22\\"\\u003EShowMore\\u003C/a\\u003E\\u003C/span\\u003E\\u003Cspan style=\\"display:none\\" class=\\"review-full-text\\"\\u003ESomething'

print(data.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode_escape'))
```

[7.2.4. Python Specific Encodings](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings)